# reload data while using separate datasource for collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

thanks for any help or advice in advance. I needed two collection views for a single ViewController so I decided to separate one of them to it's class. Here's what I got so far :

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

public var homeView: HomeView?;
public let calendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate = CalendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate();

public var month = Cal.currentMonth!;
public var year = Cal.currentYear!;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    homeView = HomeView(self).load();
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TodoCell", for: indexPath);
    return cell;
}

public func switchToNextMonth() {
    if(self.month == 12) {
        self.month = 1;
        self.year = self.year + 1;
        calendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate.year = self.year;
    } else {
        self.month = self.month + 1;
    }
    calendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate.month = self.month;

    ****//NEED TO RELOAD DATA HERE! ****
}

public func switchToPreviousMonth() {
    if(self.month == 1) {
        self.month = 12;
        self.year = self.year - 1;
        calendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate.year = self.year;
    } else {
        self.month = self.month - 1;
    }
    calendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate.month = self.month;
    **** //NEED TO RELOAD DATA HERE! ****


}

class CalendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate : NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    //ALL THE CODE FOR THE SEPARATE COLLECTIONVIEW IS HERE!

}
```

It's working fine on initial data but how I can I reload the data and reflect the changes on my view from there? If it was conforming to `UICollectionView`or `UIViewController` I could do that but how would I do the same with a separate class for `DataSource`?

Comment: You usually call `collectionView1.reloadData()` or `collectionView2.reloadData()`. `reloadData()` automatically reloads data from the dataSource assigned to the given collectionView.

Comment: @Purpose That's the problem reloadData() is a method of UICollectionView protocol, I'm not conforming to that. I just needed the dataSource the view is handling that so my collectionView doesn't have a method for reloadData().

Comment: I don’t think there is a UICollectionView protocol you can conform to. There are only collection views which you can make accessible in your UIViewController and then call reloadData() on them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the access to the separate collectionView as `calendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate.collectionView.reloadData()` or you can write a method that call the `collectionView.reloadData()` such as:

```
class CalendarCollectionViewDataSourceAndDelegate : NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

   let collectionView: UICollectionView

   //Init method and other dataSource and delegate methods

   func reload() {
       self.collectionView.reloadData()
   }
}
```